# Let $F:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^n$ a transformation of class $C^1$. Supose that $dF_{x_0}$ is inyective.

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Let $F:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^n$ a transformation of class $C^1$. Supose that $dF_{x_0}$ is inyective. Prove that there exist an $\varepsilon>0$ such that if $G$ is another transformation $C^1$ such that $||dF_{x_0}-dG_{x_0}||<\varepsilon$ then $G$ is locally injective in $x_0$.

Please help with this problem. I dont know how to approach it.

Comment: A map $F$ with $DF_xo$ injective is called an immersion. What results do you in relation to immersions?

Comment: I just can use the inverse and implicit theorem, or any basic result.

Comment: O.K, how about this: Since you have an injective map between the tangent spaces $T_{x0}$ and $T_{f(x_0)$ and both are of the same dimension, the map between the tangent spaces is both an injection and a surjection, i.e., a linear isomorphism between tangent spaces. Then there exists a local inverse in a neighborhood of $x_0$. Show, using inverse function theorem, that if $DG_{xo}$ is close-enough to $DF_{xo}$ , that the same applies to $DG_{xo}$ , i.e., the tangent map from $T_{xo}$ to $T_G_{xo}$ is also a linear isomorphism, so the Inverse Fn. Thm. also applies.

Comment: I tried to give a more detailed suggestion as an answer. Please tell me if you like the explanation.

Comment: What is the norm $\Vert\cdot\Vert$ you're using here? Linear operators can have many norms.

Comment: Euclidean norm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the conditions of the problem, we have that the map $DF_{xo}$ from $T_{xo}$ to $T_{F(xo)}$ is injective. Since the map $DF$ is an injective linear map from $\mathbb R^n$ to $\mathbb R^n$ (i.e., between vector spaces of the same dimension) , then it is also surjective, i.e., $DF_{xo}$ is a linear isomorphism between tangent spaces, so that the conditions of the inverse function theorem for the existence of a differentiable local inverse  in a 'hood $U_{xo}$ of $xo$. Now, this inverse exists in an open 'hood ( Neighborhood = 'hood; the 'hood ). Now, if $||DG_{xo}-DF_{xo}||< \epsilon$ , for $\epsilon$ small-enough , then $DG_{xo}$ lies in the 'hood $U_{xo} $ where $F$ is invertible, then you can show that $G$ and $DG$ both also satisfy the conditions for the existence of a local inverse, and therefore , $DG_{xo}$ is locally-injective.

Comment: So $\epsilon$ can be taked less than the radius of the 'hood?? And another question (to apply the inverse theorem) why the Jacobian $J(p)\neq 0$ (for $G$)?

Comment: Yes; you can take $\epsilon$ to be any value, since you're asked to show that there exists an $\epsilon$ for which it works. And $J(p) \neq 0$ Since $Df(p)$ is a linear isomorphism between the tangent spaces, so that it is invertible, so $J(p)\neq 0$

Comment: Thanks your answer really helpme.

Comment: Glad it helped, Luis.